# network interface speed

Tags: c#, windows-xp

I want to get my network interface's Name, Speed, and MAC Address.

```
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher { Scope = GetConnectedScope(target, "cimv2") };

        try
        {
           searcher.Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT MACAddress, Speed, Name FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");

            var nicList = new List<NetworkInterfaceModel>();
            foreach (var item in searcher.Get())
            {
                nicList.Add(new NetworkInterfaceModel
                {
                    NetworkInterfaceName = (string)item["Name"],
                    NetworkInterfaceSpeed = (double)(item["Speed"] != null ? (ulong) item["Speed"] : 0)/1000/1000,
                    MacAddress = (string)item["MACAddress"]
                });
            }
```

For Windows 7 and Vista it work just fine, but for XP and Windows Server 2003 it didn't collect the speed. How can I get the speed for XP and Server 2003?

Answer (score 2):

You can get networks name using windows cmd:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan show interfaces";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
string s = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string s1 = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("SSID"));
s1 = s1.Substring(s1.IndexOf(":"));
s1 = s1.Substring(2, s1.IndexOf("\n")).Trim();
p.WaitForExit();

namelabel.Text = s1;
```

for MAC Address:

```
 IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
 byte[] macAddr = new byte[6];
 uint macAddrLen = (uint)macAddr.Length;
 UInt32 nRet = 0;
 uint nAddress = BitConverter.ToUInt32(IP.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
 nRet = SendARP(nAddress, 0, macAddr, ref macAddrLen);
 if (nRet == 0)
 {
     string[] sMacAddress = new string[(int)macAddrLen];

     for (int i = 0; i < macAddrLen; i++)
     {
         sMacAddress[i] = macAddr[i].ToString("x2");
         string macAddress += sMacAddress[i] + (i < macAddrLen - 1 ? ":" : "");

     }
 }
```

and about speed you can use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

Start with adding a timerInteval(How fast you want to change to the new value) a NetworkInteface and a timer:

```
private const double timerUpdate = 1000;
private NetworkInterface[] nicArr;
private Timer timer;
```

Then Continue using the folowing componets on start up:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeNetworkInterface();
        InitializeTimer();
    }
```

Componets:

```
private void InitializeNetworkInterface()
{
    // Grab all local interfaces to this computer
    nicArr = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

    // Add each interface name to the combo box
    for (int i = 0; i < nicArr.Length; i++)
        comboBox1.Items.Add(nicArr[i].Name); //you add here the interface types in a combobox and select from here WiFi, ethernet etc...

    // Change the initial selection to the first interface
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
private void InitializeTimer()
{
     timer = new Timer();
     timer.Interval = (int)timerUpdate;
     timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
     timer.Start();
 }
```

Timer's tick

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateNetworkInterface();                
}
```

With this void you update the ping:

```
public void UpdatePing()
{     
    try
    {
        Ping myPing = new Ping();
        PingReply reply = myPing.Send(textBox1.Text, 1000);
        if (reply != null)
        {
            label17.Text = reply.Status.ToString();
            label18.Text = reply.RoundtripTime.ToString();                    
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        label17.Text = "ERROR: You have Some TIMEOUT issue";
        label18.Text = "ERROR: You have Some TIMEOUT issue";                
    }
}
```

and finally use this to show the speed in network form:

```
private void UpdateNetworkInterface()
{
    // Grab NetworkInterface object that describes the current interface
    NetworkInterface nic = nicArr[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];

    // Grab the stats for that interface
    IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = nic.GetIPv4Statistics();

    // Calculate the speed of bytes going in and out
    // NOTE: we could use something faster and more reliable than Windows Forms Tiemr
    //       such as HighPerformanceTimer http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2006/12/21/high_resolution_timer_in_net_2_0.html

    // Update the labels
    speedlbl.Text = nic.Speed.ToString();
    interfaceTypelbl.Text = nic.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString();            
    bytesReceivedlbl.Text = interfaceStats.BytesReceived.ToString();
    bytesSentlbl.Text = interfaceStats.BytesSent.ToString();

    int bytesSentSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesSent - double.Parse(label10.Text)) / 1024;
    int bytesReceivedSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesReceived - double.Parse(label11.Text)) / 1024;

    bytescomelbl.Text = bytesSentSpeed.ToString() + " KB/s";
    bytessentlbl.Text = bytesReceivedSpeed.ToString() + " KB/s";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Win32_NetworkAdapter` doesn't support the `speed` property under XP, As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx :

> Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, Windows 2000, and Windows NT 4.0:  This property has not been implemented yet. It returns a NULL value by default.

Instead, use the `CIM_NetworkAdapter` class with the same property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387931(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Then you may be out of luck doing it via WMI if you want to support legacy versions of Windows.

Comment: then maybe have sugesten how to do this without wmi

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Net;
foreach (NetworkInterface netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
    Debug.WriteLine(netInterface.Name); // Name
    Debug.WriteLine(netInterface.Speed); // Speed
    Debug.WriteLine(netInterface.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()); // MAC
}
```