# How can I get task manager performance category send and receive speed in C#?

Tags: c#

[image: How can I get this datas?]

I tried network monitor open source codes but not working. I wanna get current receive and send speed with C#.

And I tried this https://enginpolat.com/csharp-ile-network-activity-monitor-yazalim/ but not working too idk can you help me guys thank you so much. (and 220 characters is so hard :/)

Comment: Use [System.Net.NetworkInformation Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation?view=net-7.0). Look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196642/5045688 how to do it.

Comment: i tried but seems not working and when double parse try "input string was not in a correct format" 

https://prnt.sc/q5TIAlPYtUqv